# Excel Macro - Add new range to existing Formula Office 2010

Tags: excel, vba

My macro inserts 8 lines of a new job to a Summary Spreadsheet.  These lines link to a different file name and has a subtotal included as a =sum() formula (for each job).  My Grand total now does not include this new subtotal range in my previous 4 job summary.  There will be more jobs added later so it has to keep working relative to the future jobs being potentially added.  Looking for an easy way to add this new range to my existing formula within the Grand Totals Cell.  Thanks for the help.

Right now the Cell contains this formula: =G37+G29+G21+G13  (these are my for job summary subtotals)
After adding my 8 new rows of a new job I will have to add the Cell "G45" to the above formula within the macro and if I add another job it will be "G53".  The Cell to add is always 3 rows above the formula I want to add it to but the formulas has to continue to work as the jobs will be updated daily or at least weekly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your code and we can have a look

Comment: Also examples of your workbook(s) and sheets would be handy too.

Comment: so is it =Sum() or is it =G37+ect?   All you are going to be doing is parsing the forumla then rebuilding it once you added the new range.  You need to supply the code you are currently using or are you using any?  in short:  Read the cells formula into a string.  Parse the string parts.  add new range.  Add formula back to cell.  give it a try and post your code.

Answer (score 0):

just append the range to the sum function.

```
=SUM(A1:A6)
```

say now I want to add in cells C1 through C6

```
=SUM(A1:A6:C1:C6)
```

say now I want to add in cell D5

```
=SUM(A1:A6:C1:C6,D5)
```

say now I want to add in cells E1 through E6

```
=SUM(A1:A6:C1:C6,D5,E1:E6)
```

Comment: How do I append a range in a macro to an existing formula is the question?